# Can I get the demographic information with Instagram Graph API of other user than mine?

Tags: facebook, instagram

I want to be able to get a user's `audience_country`, `audience_city`, as seen in the IG User's insight (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights). Is it possible to query other user's demographic information?

Comment: No, that is not possible. You need a user access token from the user you want to query this data for.

Comment: Unfortunate, I heard you could do it with the old instagram API but thanks for confirming! @CBroe